# Assign unique IDs Dynamically to each images inside tds Jquery.

Tags: jquery, html

I want to assign unique IDs to all the images inside the td in  each tr, for each row different letter, followed by number: eg tr 1, I want all IDs to be like this: a1, a2, a3, etc. tr 2 b1, b2, bc, etc. the way the IDS are in tr1, that’s how I want to achieve this in Jquery but dynamically!  can someone kindly help me with this simple; tricky challenge please, , Thanks for your time!

this is my table

```
<table style="align:center">
    <tr>
     <td ColSpan="7">A </td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" id="a1" class="a"   /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" id="a2"  /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" id="a3"  /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" id="a3"  /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" id="a5"  /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" id="a6"  /></td>
     <td ColSpan="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td ColSpan="7">B </td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" id="b1"  /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td ColSpan="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td ColSpan="7">C </td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" id="c1"  /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td><img src="images/ snp.gif"   /></td>
     <td ColSpan="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand corretly, is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/5zzqvhdc/

Comment: Do you really have spaces in the filename for your `snp.gif` image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Unique image IDs</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.fn.addImageIDs = function(){
                return this.each(function(){
                    var thisTable = $(this);
                    var thisIdGroups = thisTable.data('imageIdGroups').split(',');
                    thisTable.find('tr').each(function() {
                        var thisRow = $(this);
                        var thisRowIdPrefix = thisIdGroups[ thisRow.index() ];
                        thisRow.find('img').each(function(i) {
                            var naturalIndex = i+1;
                            var thisImage = $(this);
                            thisImage.attr('id', '' + thisRowIdPrefix + naturalIndex);
                        });
                    });
                });
            };
            $(document).on('ready', function() {
                $('[data-image-id-groups]').addImageIDs();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table data-image-id-groups="a,b,c,d,e,f,etc.">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/ snp.gif" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this perfect solutions, it works accordingly; i want the IDs to be in Capital letters, where do i modify?, Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks again, i managed to modify the html image-id groups!, i'm greateful

Comment: Glad I helped. You can use data attributes both in javascript and css, short info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table tr').each(function(trIndex, trValue) {
    // First loop through all table rows
    $(trValue).find('td').each(function(index, value) {
        // Then loop through all tds, we skip the first one
        if( index == 0 ) {
            return true;
        }

        // Then give the td the id attribute with a String.fromCharCode 
        // This can be conveniently used to get the alphabetic characters if we add 65 (65 is A, 66 is B, etc...)
        $(value).attr('id', String.fromCharCode(trIndex+65) + index);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kje687zv/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var prefix = '';
    $('td', this).each(function(j) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (j == 0) {
            // get the value in the first <td> of the <tr>
            prefix = $this.text().toLowerCase();
        } else {
            // update the next <td>s
            $this.attr('id', prefix + j);
        }
    });
});
```